# SQL Transformation

Tags: sql, dbix-class

I have a properly working query

```
select A.*, B.*
from A left join B on A.id = B.id and B.country = 'USA'
```

Now with left join I can put only 1 condition ( A.id = B.id).  So I have to put B.country = 'USA' part somewhere else. Is there any workaround? I can use subqueries.

Update: I have to work with a framework (DBIx::Class) where I have defined single condition ( Id matching)  in Schema and it is not straightforward to alter that.

Comment: I don't even know what this question means.  Why do you think you can only use one `JOIN` condition?

Comment: You can put two conditions on the JOIN, but in your example, by putting a condition on the LEFT JOIN table, you are making it into a full join

Comment: Why are you unable to use multiple conditions on the join?

Comment: Are you trying to define a complex join condition in your schema definition class? So that you can do `$row->b_usa` for example?

Answer (score 2):

You could break B into a subquery and filter there instead of at the join

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT *
FROM B
WHERE COUNTRY = 'USA'
) B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: How I can convert it to use with DBIx::Class ?